# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2' with Python 2.7.11

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, ssl, openssl

I am having issues getting tls v1.2 support for my python installation on my mac.

This is my openssl version:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

And here is my python version:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.11
```

This is how I am testing:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'
```

Reading this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html
It says:

> Some behavior may be platform dependent, since calls are made to the
>   operating system socket APIs. The installed version of OpenSSL may
>   also cause variations in behavior. For example, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2
>   come with openssl version 1.0.1.

So I have the requirements for tlsv1.2 support with my installation of OpenSSL 1.0.2h.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please check that you have not only installed the new version of openssl but that you actually use it inside python, i.e. `import ssl\nprint ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I reinstalled with 'brew install python --with-brewed-openssl'.

Comment: gprime, can you write that as an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the openssl version python was using did not support TLS 1.2.

I installed openssl with brew and then reinstalled python telling it to use the openssl i installed with brew:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install openssl
$ brew install python --with-brewed-openssl
```

Then everything worked!

Comment: Any solutions without installing latest Python?

Comment: Sorry, not that I know of.

Comment: Is there a similar solution for ubuntu, @gprime ? I have the same exact issue, but with Django on Ubuntu.

Comment: trying this today: Error: invalid option: --with-brewed-openssl

Comment: appear homebrew basically "already uses a brewed openssl" no matter what these days (though a specific version, do `brew edit python` to see which)