# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2' with Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ssl

I am having an issue that is eerily similar to [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304907/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-protocol-tlsv1-2-with-python). I cannot use the answer there because I am on Ubuntu, and `brew` is for Mac. When I try to launch my Django server, (`python manage.py runsslserver`) I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'

I know I have OpenSSL installed for Python, as when I run `import ssl` and then `print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` in my Python environment, I get:

> OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

There must be something really simple I am missing here. Any help at all is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your question your are using Python 2.7.6. Looking at the [documentation for ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) you will see:

> ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
>   ...Available only with openssl version 1.0.1+.
>   **New in version 2.7.9.**

Thus, you need at least version 2.7.9 of Python. Either you upgrade your system to get an newer version or get some pre-packaged newer Python version like [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/linux.html).

Comment: I have python `2.7.6`. How would I update to `2.7.9`

Comment: @ifconfig: to cite the last sentence of my answer: *"Either you **upgrade your system** to get an newer version or get some pre-packaged newer Python version like Anaconda"*.

Comment: Okay, I found it. [PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) has been deprecated since 2.7.13, it should be replaced with `OP_NO_SSLv3`.