# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2' on windows when using coursera-dl package

Tags: python, pip, choco, coursera-api

i wanted to download from coursera using coursera-dl package on windows
it kept giving that message

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'
```

so i searched through stackoverflow and found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304907/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-protocol-tlsv1-2-with-python)
which says that i have first install openssl and then install python
but it still gives me that err .

Answer (score 0):

i have searched and found an answer
the problem was that i installed coursera-dl first and then python and openssl
but you must first install openssl then python with openssl then coursera-dl
also you might find an err call

```
HTTPError:400 Client Error : Bad Request for url : https://api.coursera.org/api/login/v3
```

you shall close the all tabs open on browser related to coursera web site
also overwhelm the server that repeat the command

```
coursera-dl -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD> <COURSENAME>
```

until it starts to download